# Stripe: This Element will be mounted to a DOM element that contains child nodes

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm running stripe v3 and it's giving me this warning in the web console.

```
This Element will be mounted to a DOM element that contains child nodes.
```

1. Why does it matter if the element contains "child nodes".
2. How should this best be resovled to remove the warning and resolve the issue.

My Stripe code is currently the same code recommended in the setup of Stripe Elements.

Ref: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart

```
// Create a Stripe client
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_bJA9VLD3BN4LYxPWPfJ5vcjk');

// Create an instance of Elements
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    lineHeight: '18px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Handle form submission
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

1. It is an issue because the child nodes will be replaced with the Element.
2. Ensure that the DOM node you're mounting the Element on does not have any child nodes.
   E.g. in your example, ensure that the `card-element` div does not have any child nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you are using the recommended setup code.  The code given has a comment in the card-element:

```
<div id="card-element">
  <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
</div>
```

Remove that and enjoy an error-free console.

Comment: Given that the error doesn't occur in the iframe on Stripe docs I don't think the comment was the issue.

Comment: Interesting catch.  In my current project, removing the comment got rid of the error.  I can't confirm why, just that it did.  Hopefully, it works for other obsessive programmers.

And, thanks for the edit, I should have added the code for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

it's too late but might help someone else.

You no need to write

```
<input type="text" id="card_number">
```

you can replace input line with div

```
 <div id="card_number" class="form-control"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your front-end code is probably nesting something inside the stripe element.  This is not allowed because stripe is going to nest it's own DOM elements within `#card-element`. The `#card-element` must remain empty.

Example:
You write this...

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="card-element">Elements</label>
    <div id="card-element" class="form-control"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it renders to this:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="card-element">Elements</label>
    <div id="card-element" class="form-control">
      <div class="__PrivateStripeElement"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When loaded on the page, stripe adds their own `div` to `#card-element` that contains an `iframe` with many many lines of additional code.